# How do I check that a filename conforms to a pattern?

Tags: shell-script, grep, filenames, patterns

I'm tasked with writing a shell script which checks that a filename conforms to a specific pattern and I'm not sure how to go about it.

The filename should follow a pattern which looks like:

```
(Project-ID)_(Env)_(Source-System-ID)_(DataDescriptor)_(CCYYMMDD)_(Seq)_(Freeformat)_(codepage)
```

- Project_ID should be alphanumeric and between 3-8 characters.
- Env should consist of a 3 character code (DEV, SYT, SIT, UAT or PRD)
- Source-System-ID should be a variable number
- DataDescriptor should be alphanumeric such as CUST
- CCYYMMDD should be a date in the format CCYYMMDD
- Seq should be a number such as 01, 02, 03 etc
- Freeformat should be alphanumeric - used to give the filename additional description
- codepage should represent the file extension such as .ascii or .EBCDIC

An example file might look like:

```
ABC_PRD_00227_ACC_20130128_01_LTSB.CP1252
```

If the file doesn't conform to the pattern it would be good if some sort of warning could be displayed.

Comment: Sadly I do not have time right now to hammer out a grep pattern for you, but that is most likely the method the answer will be based on. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/ for a simple intro

Comment: May I ask how many example files you do have and what program did generate these? Or is this homework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you use a recent version of `zsh`, `ksh93` or `bash` and the filename doesn't contain newline characters:

```sh
# split up the filename into its parts
IFS=_ read -r pjid env srcid desc date seq free <<< "$filename"

# extract the codepage from the free text
code=${free##*.}
free=${free%.*}

# validate
if  [[ $pjid  =~ ^[[:alnum:]]{3,8}$ ]]                                  &&
    [[ $env   == "DEV" || $env == "SYT" || ... ]]                       &&
    [[ $srcid =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]                                      &&
    [[ $desc  =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]                                      &&
    [[ $date  =~ ^[[:digit:]]{8}$ ]] && date -d "$date" >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    [[ $seq   =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]                                      &&
    [[ $free  =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]                                      &&
    [[ $code  =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]  # need specific codepage validation?
then
    echo "file name format is OK"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you @stephane. I have and continue to learn from your attention to detail.

Answer (score 1):

My find-fu is weak today, so I was unable to get find to accept my regex with -regex/-iregex and the different -regextype options.

This one is a bit slower, but will hopefully help you out:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -P '[[:alnum:]]{3,8}_(DEV|SYT|SIT|UAT|PRD)_\d+_[[:alnum:]]+_\d\d\d\d[0-1]\d[0-3]\d_\d\d_[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+'

./ABC_PRD_00227_ACC_20130128_01_LTSB.CP1252
```

Assuming you want to find files not matching the pattern, just add the -v switch to grep.